# Can't type in redux-form Field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I cannot type anything in my form Fields. I searched for solutions, but found none of which solved the problem. Looking at simular problems, it is probably a reducer issue. So what am I doing wrong?

Using: react 15.4.2, redux-form 6.5.0, react-router 3.0.2

LoginForm.js

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    onSubmit(values) {
        console.log(values.email)
    }

    render() {

        var { handleSubmit } = this.props; // Provided by redux-form

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
              <label>E-mail</label>
              <Field name='email' component='input' type='text' />
              <button type="submit">Login</button> 
            </form>
        )
    }
}

const form = reduxForm({
    form: 'LoginForm'
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(form(LoginForm));
```

reducers.js

```
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer
});

export default combinedReducers;
```

index.js

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

// temp
const Dashboard = () => { return <div>Dasboard</div> };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(combinedReducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route pathp="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. I have replicated your code and it works as expected. You can see the code here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kf13qs_C-9323-46SGH.

Comment: Do you get any errors or something?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas tnx for replying and testing my code. Since it works for you the code should be fine. Then it might be my setup. What details should I provide? It's a very simple app, and there is not much more to show.

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean "I cannot type anything"? Is the input field disabled or non reponsive? Do you get error messages?

Comment: When I click in the Field and try to type anything it is not showing up in the Filed. No messages, no error, no console logs. The Field is doing something since I can see the cursor in the Field responding to input (meaning the flickering cursor indicating where you are typing stops flickering druring typing, so it receives input).

Comment: I haven't seen or heard about this sort of issue anywhere. Care to try it on a different browser?

Comment: Good suggestion! Tried it on IE. It shows the character I am typing for a short moment before taking it away again. Seems like the input is received but the state of the component it not updated, and since the Field value is connected to the state it is taken away?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still have no clue what went wrong, but after I reinstalled react, react-redux and redux-form, everything worked.

Tnx to @Deividas Karžinauskas for the help and time. Thanks to his answers I knew the code was OK and it had to be something else.

Comment: Aside from `pathp`, I don't see any glaring errors in your code.